# Else Syntax Error Python

Tags: python, if-statement

```
if len(user_hash) > 0:
  with open(log_file, "w") as log_f:
    for name in user_hash:
        log_f.write("Name:%s \n Email: %s" % (name, email)

    else len(user_hash) < 0:
       print "Nothing happened :("
```

I keep getting a syntax error on the else statement and I am unsure why it keeps producing this error. I don't have any other else statements in the same def and it still gives error. What do I do?

Comment: You need to indent the code.

Comment: Please read the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to get an understanding of how to format code in your posts.  Don't insert all those `<br>` tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your log_f.write statement is also missing a trailing ')', which is likely confusing the parser...and the indentation doesn't look right. Cut and paste problem?

Comment: The question is on `else`.. accepted answer, `parenthesis`.. Weird but True.. :)

Answer (score 8):

In Python, the `else` statement takes no conditions:

```
if condition:
   do_1()
else:
   do_else()
```

In your case, since you want to evaluate another condition, after the `if`, use an `elif`:

```
if condition1:
    do_1()
elif condition2:
    do_2()
... # you can have as many elifs as you want
else:
    do_else()
```

> Note: Read the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do `else` like that in Python. You should do (assuming your tabs are correct in real life):

`elif len(user_hash) < 0:`

and as mentioned, you're missing a close paren.

Comment: As written, his `else` belongs to the `for`, and a `for` statement can't take an `elif`. That looks like it might be an indentation error brought on by poor copying, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't supply a condition with an `else` statement.  `else` means "everything else" --- that is, everything else but whatever conditions you specified in an earlier `if`.  It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish with that `else`, but perhaps you mean it to be an `if`.

It could also be an `elif` ("else if"), but if you mean it to be an `else` for the earlier `if` clause, then you need to unindent it so it's at the same indentation level as the `if`.  An `if` and it's `else`/`elif` have to line up at the same indentation level.

(There is such a thing as an `else` clause for a `for` statement, but it doesn't look like that's what you want here.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do [else](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) with [for](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) loops in Python, but you'll need to balance your parentheses on:

```
log_f.write("Name:%s \n Email: %s" % (name, email)
```

which should actually be

```
log_f.write("Name:%s \n Email: %s" % (name, email))
```

(Note the extra final parenthesis.)

Answer (score 0):

if and else must be in the same column align, this work for me.

Comment: for/else is a perfectly valid python construct. `else XX:` is not however.

Answer (score 0):

Brackets in the log_f.write line don't cancel out each other, add an extra closing bracket at the end, like this:

```
log_f.write("Name:%s \n Email: %s" % (name, email))
```