# syntax error in if...else condition

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax, nested, conditional-statements

I'm learning programming in Python and I'm stuck with a syntax error in the line 8 in the following code

```
x = int(input('Add x:\n'))
y = int(input('Add y:\n'))
if x == y :
    print('x and y are equal')
else :
    if x < y :
        print('x is less than y')
    else x > y :
        print('x is greater than y')
```

I just don't see what's wrong there.

The full error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compare.py", line 8
    else x > y :
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Please, **always** include the full error output when asking a question. That makes it easier for us to diagnose and for future visitors to find this question if they have the same error.

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474599/else-syntax-error-python) a dupe, but clearly this question has the better answer(s).

Answer (score 2):

`else` takes no condition. It's just `else:`, nothing more; the block is executed when the `if` condition (and any `elif`conditions) didn't match. Use `elif` if you must have another condition to test on.

In your case, just use

```
if x == y:
    print('x and y are equal')
elif x < y:
    print('x is less than y')
else:
    print('x is greater than y')
```

There is no need to explicitly test for `x > y`, because that's the only option remaining (`x` is not equal or less, ergo, it is greater), so `else:` is fine here.

Note that I collapsed your nested `if ... else` statement into an `elif ... else` extension on the top-level `if`.