# Why do I get a Syntax error when using Else and not Elif?

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm just writing a simple if/elif/else statement and I keep getting a syntax error when using else but not elif. They are being used in the exact same place. Here are two examples:

```
fruit = 'banana'
if 'e' in fruit:
   print('found it')
elif 'b' in fruit:
   print('found it')

fruit = 'banana'
if 'e' in fruit:
    print('found it')
else 'b' in fruit:
    print('found it')
```

The elif code runs with no problems, whereas the code using else produces a syntax error:

```
line 4
    else 'b' in fruit:
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Because `else` can't contains logical condition.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? What makes you think that ``else`` could be used like ``elif``?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [syntax error in if...else condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50079139/syntax-error-in-if-else-condition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are confusing between how `else` and `elif` works.

`elif` is used when you want to handle all situations which does not fall into `if` case and matches a specific condition whereas `else` is used for all conditions that do not fall under `if` and that's why in this statement [`else 'b' in fruit:`] `else` is not supposed to receive any condition.

Answer (score 1):

The else keyword catches anything which isn't caught by the condition used in if or elif section.so it dose not contain any condition.